# Is there something like NSUserDefaults in Django?

Tags: python, ios, django, cocoa, cocoa-touch

On iOS, we can write something value with a key like this in Objective-C:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"myKey"];
```

or in Swift:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "myKey")
```

Does Django or Python offer a basic typed key-value store like `NSUserDefaults` on in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch on OS X and iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django and iOS are very different platforms, `NSUserDefaults` is a client-side datastore whereas with Django you would need a server-side datastore.

Because the server is not unique to a user you would usually just use a database (could be as lightweight as SQLite) and then either have user signups or something like that so you have a unique client ID to associate with the data.

Comment: I get that the platforms are different. I suppose I could really write my own little Django app to create a key-value object and back it by whatever database my Django project uses?